# Same indent for whole custom defined environment?

Tags: environments, indentation

I defined an environment that looks like this:

```
\newcounter{question}
\newenvironment{question}[2][]{\refstepcounter{question}\noindent \textbf{Question~\thequestion: #1} #2\\}
```

In my latex document I use it like this:

```
\question{What is the difference between System.gc() and Runtime.gc()?}
\question{If an object reference is set to null, will the Garbage Collector immediately free the memory held by that object?}
```

And this generates the following output:

[image]

However, I would like that the word 'held' of the second line in question 7 has the same indent as the word if. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why aren't you using a list environment (`enumitem` would make it much easier). But if you do not want, then consider putting your "Question #:" into a fixed-width box and using `\hangindent`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the correction. My browser spellchecker isn't that smart (identifying TeX commands).

Comment: The use of `\question` is wrong this way! I think the 2nd argument is a misuse as well.

Comment: The reason that I'm not using a list environment is that these kind of questions are distributed over a big document and in between there is many other content.

Comment: What's the problem with this? You can use a list environment and let it use a specific counter as a label. There's no problem with that.

Comment: Ok, then my question would be how to achieve that with a list environment. I have around 500 uses of \question{...} and what to change all of that manually :)

Comment: Also, you could define a markup function to identify those words, i.e., `\newcommand*\fn[1]{#1}` does no harm, and you can use `\fn{System.gc()}` and may be later change the style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a `list` environment with one `\item` for each question. And not to reset the counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcounter{question}
\newcommand\MyQuestionList[1]{%
  \begin{list}{%
      \refstepcounter{question}%
      \textbf{Question \thequestion:}%
    }{%
      \settowidth{\labelwidth}{\textbf{Question \thequestion:}}
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
    }
  \item #1
  \end{list}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\MyQuestionList{\lipsum[2]}

\MyQuestionList{New qestion}

Set the question couter to 25, i.e. the next question is 26.
\setcounter{question}{25}

\MyQuestionList{\lipsum[3]}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

I have set the counter to 25 just to show that the indentation follows the label for each question.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to define a new `enumerate-like` environment with `enumitem`. For a continuous numbering, use the `resume` option of `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[questions]{label=\bfseries Question \arabic*: , align=left, widest=\textbf{999}, leftmargin=*, ref=\arabic*}
\def\qu{\item}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}%
    \qu What is the difference between System.gc() and Runtime.gc()?\label{q-1}
    \qu If an object reference is set to null, will the Garbage Collector immediately free the memory held by that object?
    \setcounter{questionsi}{99}
    \qu Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. 
\end{questions}
Proof of \ref{q-1}. —
\begin{questions}[resume]
    \qu Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text.
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You also can have a variable list left margin, according the value of the counter (between 1 and 9, or between 10 and 99, &c.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[questions]{label=\bfseries Question \arabic*: , align=left, leftmargin=*, ref=\arabic*}
\def\qu{\item}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}%
    \qu What is the difference between System.gc() and Runtime.gc()?\label{q-1}
    \qu If an object reference is set to null, will the Garbage Collector immediately free the memory held by that object?
    \setcounter{questionsi}{97}
\end{questions}
Proof of \ref{q-1}. —
\begin{questions}[resume, widest=\textbf{99}, ]%
    \qu Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text.
    \qu Another test text. Another test text. Another test text. Another test text. Another test text.
\end{questions}
\begin{questions}[resume, widest=\textbf{999}, ]
    \qu Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text. Some test text.
    \qu Another test text. Another test text. Another test text. Another test text. Another test text.
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That does not comply with what the OP wants. He wants it to be numbered continously.

Comment: @TeXnician: What do you mean exactly with ‘numbered continuously’?  There's no gap in enumerate environments numberings.

Comment: See StefanH's answer for explanation (numbering continously in document, not per list environment).

Comment: But that is easy to do with `enumitem` and the `resume` option. I'll post an example.

Comment: Yes, but do not expect an OP to read manuals ;) I'm glad you edited (I think this short answer is more convenient than the whole definition of an own list).

Comment: Perhaps you should use `fontenc` in addition to `inputenc` in your answer.

Comment: @Skillmon: You're right, though it's not directly connected with the problem at hand. We shouldn't set a bad example…

Comment: @Bernard it's still missing inside of the second code snippet :)

Comment: Right! I simply forgot I added a variant. That's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Just another solution without a list (actually two solutions, one with `\hangindent` and one without):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcounter{question}
\newcommand{\qsparbox}[2][\relax]{%
    \refstepcounter{question}%
    \ifx#1\relax%
        \setbox0\hbox{\textbf{Question~\thequestion:}}%
    \else%
        \setbox0\hbox{\textbf{Question~\thequestion: #1}}%
    \fi%
    \noindent\usebox0\hskip1em\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1em-\wd0}{#2}\\%
}
\newcommand{\qshangindent}[2][\relax]{%
    \refstepcounter{question}%
    \ifx#1\relax%
        \setbox0\hbox{\textbf{Question~\thequestion:}}%
    \else%
        \setbox0\hbox{\textbf{Question~\thequestion: #1}}%
    \fi%
    \par\hangindent3em%
    \noindent\usebox0\hskip1em#2\par%
}


\begin{document}
Using \verb|\parbox|:

\qsparbox{If an object reference is set to null, will the Garbage Collector immediately free the memory held by that object?}

\qsparbox[test]{If an object reference is set to null, will the Garbage Collector immediately free the memory held by that object?}

\vspace{1em}
Using \verb|\hangindent|:
\qshangindent{If an object reference is set to null, will the Garbage Collector immediately free the memory held by that object?}

\qshangindent[test]{If an object reference is set to null, will the Garbage Collector immediately free the memory held by that object?}
\end{document}
```

[image: results]